# running selenium with xinit Raspberry pi

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi

Hello i am trying to run the iceweasel browser (opened by selenium-webdriver) in the raspberry Pi non windows manager.

the command to start iceweasel like i want is "xinit /usr/bin/iceweasel -e Fullscreen -a http://google.com". i simply want to relate this to selenium but I'm not sure how.
Using wheezy Debian.

selenium code:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import serial
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



driver = webdriver.Firefox()
webdriver.common.utils.free_port()
driver.get("http://0.0.0.0:3333/")


ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyAMA0',
        baudrate = 9600,
        parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=1
)



while True:
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id('keyvalue')
        abc = elem.get_attribute("value")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if abc != '':
                print (abc)
                driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('keyvalue').value = ''")
                ser.write(abc)
        else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since selenium relies on running a browser, and since the browser will only run in a windowed environment, it would appear that there is no way to do what you want in a non-windowed environment (though I would be happy to be proved wrong).

Comment: I will happily prove you wrong (i think) i was posting this on raspberry pi forums as well and one of the replies involved using "matchbox-window-manager", so i made a sh script with "matchbox-window-manager & (\r) python selenium.py" which seems to have done the trice. Note i also edited firefox_binary.py (in selenium source) so the timout was set to 60 rather then default 30

Comment: Not often I'm right, but I'm wrong again (though I might argue that you *are* running in a windowed environment, it seems futile as long as you can run the software you need).

Comment: my non windows manager i mean without loading the desktop cant remember which post referred to it as a non windows manager. im guessing the xinit is the windows manager just running the x server so looking back over my question i guess you were actually correct, now my problem resides in changing the windows size of the iceweasel browser.